# Each to one line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code like this:

```
$(this).each(function() {
    parse('button', $(this));
});
```

Is it possible to minimize `each()` to one line?

This code doesn't work:

```
$(this).each(parse('button', $(this)));
```

Comment: You mean $(this).each(function() {parse('button', $(this));});

Comment: We need to see the parse method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just this:

```
parse('button', $(this));
//----------------^^^^----your selector group either with classname or tagName
```

### update:

See if you have this html:

```
<a href='#'>test link</a><br/>
<a href='#'>test link</a><br/>
<a href='#'>test link</a><br/>
<a href='#'>test link</a><br/>
```

and this is the jQuery:

```
function parseIt(b, a){
  return $(a).text(b);
}

$(function(){
   parseIt('New Text for Buttons', $('a'));
});
```

results will be: http://jsfiddle.net/svwF9/

```
<a href='#'>New Text for Buttons</a><br/>
<a href='#'>New Text for Buttons</a><br/>
<a href='#'>New Text for Buttons</a><br/>
<a href='#'>New Text for Buttons</a><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is not line based, so you can have more than one statement on a line. You can't replace a function reference with a function call though, you still need that part of the code:

```
$(this).each(function() { parse('button', $(this)); });
```

Comment: @Steve: I edited the answer after you edited the question, to clarify why you still need all the code.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If it's that much of an issue, why not change `parse` to accommodate the arguments in `.each()`'s callback? Something like this.

```
$(this).each(parse);

function parse(index, element) {
    var e = $(element);
    var type = e.prop('tagName').toLower();

    if(type == 'button') { 
        // parse button
    }
}
```